# How to host a React App on github which is not created by using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I ve successfully deployed hosting on github by using create-react-app ,But i wonder if this hosting can be possible without create-react-app, as create-react-app is heavy for my app.

Thanks

This is my webpack.config.js output code

`output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/"),
    publicPath: "/", //BUNDLED OUTPUT WILL BE SERVED FROM HERE
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },`
and package.json looks like this

`"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode development",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "predeploy": "yarn run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  }, 
    "homepage": "https://SamalaSumanth0262.github.io/",`[image: This is my folder structure]

[image]

Comment: hosting the app doesn't have anything to to with `create-react-app`, can you explain the issue you are facing if any, github-pages need a `html` page with content thats it

Comment: @sumanthmadishetty i have edited the question with some detailed info, can you tell where i am going wrong PS: i have gh-pages package too

Comment: hey @sumanthmadishetty i have fixed it by moving the index.html to root folder.
Thanks a Lot. Appreciated....